# How to transform List<firstType> to List<SecondType>? (Apache CollectionUtils)

Tags: java, apache

I need to create method `transformer` which can to change type of objects.
For example: I have `List<Integer>  sampl`e and what change to `List<String> sample.` 
How write method to do this? I really don't understand , because I know apache already have rhis method -> `CollectionUtils.transform();   (full way - org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils.transform();` , but i can't understand how it work and how to write method whjich include all. In example(
http://www.baeldung.com/apache-commons-collection-utils, 
http://apachecommonstipsandtricks.blogspot.ru/2009/01/examples-of-functors-transformers.html) i saw how in main methods folks override rhis method, but how to write just method and how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

According to your link (http://www.baeldung.com/apache-commons-collection-utils), you need to use `CollectionUtils.collect` method, and give a `Transformer` as the 2nd argument to the method. I guess that the `collect` function iterates over the elements, and for each element calls the `transform` methods that takes the element from type A and returning an element from type B.
Overall it will look like that:

```
List<String>listOfString = CollectionUtils.collect(listOfIntegers, new 
    Transformer<Integer, String>() {
    public String transform(Integer numbers) {
   //Do whatever you need to transform it to a String and return the String.
     return number.toString() // a suggestion
    }
});
```

Another way is to just use the `stream` mechanism that java 8 has and use the `map` method that maps each element to something else.

```
listOfNum.stream().map(integer -> integer.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```